# CodenameOne: BLE initialize on iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, codenameone

I finally go my experimental app to start on my iPhone 5c, iOS 10.3.  The App is working on Android already. I'm using the CodenameOne java framework with BLE which uses the underlying Cordova BLE plug-in (https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle).

The docs say I need to call initialize() before doing anything else.  So, I call isInitialized() to see if I need to make the more time consuming method call.  If it is not initialized, then I call initialize().  I know that bluetooth is functioning on the phone, because I can connect to the target BLE chip with another app.  However, when I call initialize() it returns false.  I'm not sure if the error is coming from the plug in library or not from the iOS.

So, are there cases where the initialize() reports false (i.e. "uninitialized") but would still allow scanning for devices or even connecting?  I'm also not sure how to really debug BLE at this point.

Comment: Did you enable bluetooth and request permission as shown [here](https://github.com/chen-fishbein/bluetoothle-codenameone/blob/master/BTDemo/src/com/codename1/btle/BTDemo.java#L66-L74)?

Comment: Yes, I tried those, and on iOS, enable() and setPermissions() will through an UnsupportedException.